# Need to add to an existing formula to change cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a formula that I use to count down the days until a task is due based on the date in the due date cell. If the due date cell is blank, it leaves the Days Until Due cell blank.

The problem I have is when the Closed Date cell is filled in. Currently it stops the countdown, but if the closed date is not entered on the exact closed date, it gives a misleading number in the Days Until Due cell. What I would like to do is have it return a zero if the Closed Date cell is filled in. Below is the current formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(L18),IF(ISBLANK(J18), "", J18-TODAY()),I18)
```

- L18 is the Closed Date Cell
- J18 is the Due Date Cell
- I18 is the Days Until Due Cell

Comment: Can you give some examples of your table with the possible variation of values and the expected output? Without examples it's hard to understand, what you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula has a circular reference. In other words, it is trying to reference itself at the end (`I18`).

Replace `I18` with `0` will cause the cell to show a zero if `L18` is filled in.

[image]

Comment: CharlieRB-Looks like this will do the trick for me. Thanks.